# Passing a delegate as a method pointer

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm trying to pass a delegate to a c++ method code:

```
#pragma unmanaged
void login(char *uname, void (*cb)() )
{
  if ( strcmp(uname, "test")==0)
  {
      printf("Correct!\n");
      cb();
  }
  else
  {
      printf("False\n");
  }
}
#pragma managed
public ref class log
{
    public: delegate void successdelg();
    public: static void logme(String ^s, successdelg ^success)
    {
        login( (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s), success );
    }
};
```

But I'm getting this error : "error C2664: 'login' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'log::successdelg ^' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'"

Normally I can jump this error by just passing the method without any delegate to my c++ function but I'm using this as a library referenced to my c# project which passes the method from my c# application to the c++ dll.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but your use of `StringToHGlobalAnsi` is wrong. As mentioned in the documentation, you must call `FreeHGlobal` when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate method. Keep delegate instance passed to this method alive all time when callback function is used, because this function call doesn't add reference counter for this delegate.

Comment: Thanks, if anyone is interested in the full fix: in unmanaged add typedef void (__stdcall *cb)(); and in the login parameter change the pointer to cb in managed part: GCHandle gch = GCHandle::Alloc(successdelg);
  IntPtr ip = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(successdelg);
        cb c_b = static_cast<ANSWERCB>(ip.ToPointer()); and now just pass the c_b instead.